# Formatting nested Prolog output

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am working with a Prolog database that has a set of entities with properties and values. I would like to output every entity along with each of its properties and values.

I'm very new to Prolog, and I have something that gives me the information I need, but I need it to be formatted in a specific way.

First, **I need the property value to be wrapped in quotations**.

Second, I would *like* to have indentation and newlines to make it more readable, but this part isn't 100% necessary.

Here is a toy version:

```
% example objects
instanceOf(ball_1, physicalObject).
instanceOf(ball_2, physicalObject).
instanceOf(block_1, physicalObject).


% example properties
propertyOf(color_ball_1, ball_1).
propertyOf(size_ball_1, ball_1).

propertyOf(color_ball_2, ball_2).
propertyOf(size_ball_2, ball_2).

propertyOf(color_block_1, block_1).
propertyOf(size_block_1, block_1).


% example property values
hasValue(color_ball_1, red).
hasValue(size_ball_1, big).

hasValue(color_ball_2, blue).
hasValue(size_ball_2, small).

hasValue(color_block_1, red).
hasValue(size_block_1, small).
```

(Note: I am unable to change the actual database, so let's assume the facts have to be represented as they are.)

Here are my functors for getting all of the objects along with their properties and values:

```
% find all properties and values for one object
findEveryPropertyWithValue(Object, Properties) :-
    % get one object ...
    instanceOf(Object, physicalObject),

    % find every property of every object
    findall((Property, Value), (propertyOf(Property, Object), hasValue(Property, Value)), Properties).


% find all objects with properties and values
findAllObjects(Objects_and_Properties) :-
    % find every physicalObject with its Properties and Values
    findall((Obj, Properties), (instanceOf(Obj, physicalObject), findEveryPropertyWithValue(Obj, Properties)), Objects_and_Properties).
```

If I just run `findEveryPropertyWithValue` then it's readable, but I don't have quotes around the property values:

```
?- findEveryPropertyWithValue(Obj, Props).
Obj = ball_1,
Props = [(color_ball_1, red), (size_ball_1, big)] ;
Obj = ball_2,
Props = [(color_ball_2, blue), (size_ball_2, small)] ;
Obj = block_1,
Props = [(color_block_1, red), (size_block_1, small)].
```

But in that case I need to ask Prolog to keep finding solutions manually, and I want them all at once, which is what `findAllObjects` is for, but the output isn't readable and again lacks the quotations:

```
?- findAllObjects(Objs).
Objs = [(ball_1, [(color_ball_1, red), (size_ball_1, big)]), (ball_2, [(color_ball_2, blue), (size_ball_2, small)]), (block_1, [(color_block_1, red), (size_block_1, small)])].
```

This is what I would like the output to look like:

```
Objs = [
    (ball_1, 
        [
            (color_ball_1, "red"), 
            (size_ball_1, "big")
        ]
    ), 
    (ball_2, 
        [
            (color_ball_2, "blue"), 
            (size_ball_2, "small")
        ]
    ), 
    (block_1, 
        [
            (color_block_1, "red"), 
            (size_block_1, "small")
        ]
    )
].
```

The indentation and newlines aren't strictly necessary, but it would be nice. But the quotations are a must and I am struggling to figure out how to use `format/2` to make this work.

Here is one thing I tried:

```
formatSandbox(Formatted) :-
    findall((Object), instanceOf(Object, idPhysicalObject), Objects),

    forall(Objects, format("Here is an object: ~q", [Object])).
```

It's clearly very wrong because this is my output:

```
?- formatSandbox(X).
ERROR: source_sink `ball_1' does not exist
ERROR: source_sink `ball_2' does not exist
ERROR: source_sink `block_1' does not exist
Here is an object: _50
```

What I thought I was doing was saying "for everything in Objects, tell me what it is" but I don't know how to refer to the "current object," which is why I just put `[Object]`, but it's not right.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Note: I asked an almost identical question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76805793/querying-and-displaying-hierarchical-prolog-information), but in that one I did ask for suggestions on how the database could be improved, and I got good answers about that, so I would like to leave those there. But because I can't actually edit the database at this time, I wanted this question to focus solely on the formatting issue, let me know if I should delete this one and edit the old one! I'm not sure about the etiquette.

Comment: Which "good answers" did you get there? At least you did not mark any as the accepted answer.

Comment: Do you need to have the result in a variable? Or it is ok to only print it?

Comment: @damianodamiano, I only want it printed, it doesn't need to be in a variable. I guess I would be interested to see both ways, but as it is right now all I want is the text printed out so I can put it into another python program.

Comment: @false, my bad. I have marked one as accepted now, the one that shows an alternative data representation and also does give a formatting example. Though I seem to be unable to figure out how to use `format/2` myself to get the formatting I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the desired output with the following code:

```
format_property_value((Property, Value), Atom) :-
    format(atom(Atom), '(~w, "~w")', [Property, Value]).

format_property_value_list(PropertyValueList, Atom) :-
    maplist(format_property_value, PropertyValueList, AtomicList),
    atomic_list_concat(AtomicList, ',\n            ', Atom0),
    format(atom(Atom), '        [\n            ~w\n        ]', Atom0).

format_object_properties((Object, Properties), Atom) :-
    format_property_value_list(Properties, Atom0),
    format(atom(Atom), '    (~w,\n~w\n    )', [Object, Atom0]).

format_object_properties_list(ObjectPropertiesList, Atom) :-
    maplist(format_object_properties, ObjectPropertiesList, AtomicList),
    atomic_list_concat(AtomicList, ',\n', Atom0),
    format(atom(Atom), '[\n~w\n]', Atom0).

print_all_objects :-
    findAllObjects(ObjectPropertiesList),
    format_object_properties_list(ObjectPropertiesList, Atom),
    writeln(Atom).
```

For example:

```
?- format_property_value((color,red), Atom).
Atom = '(color, "red")'.

?- format_property_value_list([(color,red), (size,small)], Atom).
Atom = '        [\n            (color, "red"),\n            (size, "small")\n        ]'.

?- print_all_objects.
[
    (ball_1,
        [
            (color_ball_1, "red"),
            (size_ball_1, "big")
        ]
    ),
    (ball_2,
        [
            (color_ball_2, "blue"),
            (size_ball_2, "small")
        ]
    ),
    (block_1,
        [
            (color_block_1, "red"),
            (size_block_1, "small")
        ]
    )
]
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
pair_print([]).
pair_print([(A,B)]):- !,
    term_string(B,S),
    format('~2t(~w,~p)~n',[A,S]).
pair_print([(A,B)|T]):-
    term_string(B,S),
    format('~2t(~w,~p),~n',[A,S]),
    pair_print(T).

my_print([]).
my_print([(O,LP)|T]):-
    format('(~w,~n[~n',O),
    pair_print(LP),
    format(']~n)~n'),
    my_print(T).
```

```
?- findAllObjects(Objs), my_print(Objs).
(ball_1,
[
(color_ball_1,"red"),
(size_ball_1,"big")
]
)
(ball_2,
[
(color_ball_2,"blue"),
(size_ball_2,"small")
]
)
(block_1,
[
(color_block_1,"red"),
(size_block_1,"small")
]
)
```

Then you can add indentation and so on...